# Azure Function Request POST Body Encoding

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, azure-functions

I'm wondering whether encoding is something I have to explicitly handle in an Azure function (v3) triggered by an http POST.

For example... which approach is correct (s1, s2, or s3):

```
[Function("MyFancyFunction")]
public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] HttpRequestData req,
    FunctionContext executionContext)
{
    // What charset/encoding will be used if not specified?
    var s1 = req.ReadAsString();

    // Surely it can't be save to assume UTF8?
    var s2 = req.ReadAsString(Encoding.UTF8);

    // Use the charset of the first content-type
    var ct = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(req.Headers.GetValues("content-type").First());
    var s3 = req.ReadAsString(ct.Encoding);

    ...
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put together a simple test function and simple http POST console app.

The console app explicitly encodes the POST payload as Win-1252 (only chosen because it has characters from 0-255). The payload includes a 0x0080 character (utf-8 start sequence) which should cause problems if not decoded using the appropriate encoding.

Here's what the POST payload program looks like:

```
var client = new HttpClient();

var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, " http://localhost:7071/api/Function1");

req.Content = new StringContent("d\u0080d");
req.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
req.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding.Add("win-1252");
        
client.Send(req);
```

The test function looks like:

```
[Function("Function1")]
public static HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
    FunctionContext executionContext)
{
    var s1 = req.ReadAsString(); // s1 == "d\u0080d"... yippie!

    var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    return response;
}
```

The end result is that YES Azure functions will pay attention to a content-type's charset instruction and use the appropriate Encoding.

Answer (score -1):

> which approach is correct (s1, s2, or s3)

Below is the sample code which I used in my environment for encoding data and it worked for me rather than these 3 approaches I suggest to use the below given code.

```
public static async Task<string> Run(  
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,  
ILogger log)  
{  
log.LogInformation("SendMessage function requested");  
string body = string.Empty;  
using (var reader = new StreamReader(req.Body, Encoding.UTF8))  
{  
body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();  
log.LogInformation($"Message body : {body}");  
}  
log.LogInformation($"SendMessage processed.");  
return body;  
}
```

And here is the Output with the Encoded Data

[image]

Comment: It looks like you've just assumed UTF8 - StreamReader(req.Body, Encoding.UTF8). What if the POST was encoded otherwise?